# Google spreadsheet custom conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like

```
    A   B   C   D
   --------------
1 | 3   2   4   1
```

I want to highlight the max value in the row. I tried to apply a custom conditional formatting formula, but I got stuck. Something like `=A1=MAX(A1:D1)` doesn't work. I need to substitue somehow `A1` with "current" cell but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
=$A$1:$D$1=max($A$1:$D$1)
```

and see if that works..

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the requirement in a different way. Select ColumnsA:D, Format, Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is**:

```
=A1=max($A1:$D1)
```

with formatting of your choice.